# URL Rewriting, i can't $_GET it

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

in this last week i have tried to obtain a best result for my MVC php framework but without reading yet any manual of regular expression i understand a little from tutorials how this work, so my htacces file is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
ErrorDocument 502 /index.php
ErrorDocument 504 /index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)?/?([a-z]*)?([a-z_]*)?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2$3 [NC,L]
```

no numbers in my URL no uppercase letters, only lower case letters, so i try to make here a way that action function get another parameters i don't know exactly the numbers, but they are maybe one or five..anyway, after controller and action i need to get another parameters with values, and also without any restriction like `id=$3` something like:
`index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 whould be /recover/password` and the rest after `/recover/password?email=myemail@myweb.com&password=1q2w32e4tr5yt6yu7ui8i9o` and so on!
one week and i didn't find anything similar on the web! anyone can help me, tcx?

Comment: I just gotta compliment you on the title, had to laugh haha

Comment: Give some examples on what you want to accomplish. Right now it's difficult to understand where your probliem lies. Break up paragraphs into sentences for readability. Curb all "help me" and research aversion comments instead.

Comment: i want my url to look similar to this: `/recover/password?email=myemail@myweb.com&password=1q2w32e4tr5yt6yu7ui8i9o` i already have this part: `/recover/password`

Comment: for now this work: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)?/?([a-z]*)?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]` i want to be able to use `$_GET` after this, like normal use only to hide the first part `index.php?controller=$1&action=$2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need `QSA` flag here:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
ErrorDocument 502 /index.php
ErrorDocument 504 /index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z_]+)/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: wow ya i think i should read that book, what do you think? Awsome dude tcx!

Comment: Your welcome. Even askspache.com is pretty good resource for URL rewriting.